# Rails 5.1: using { where(association: @assocition) } now requires _id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, where-clause

A `transaction_record` has many `documents`.

```
class TransactionRecord < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :documents
end

class Document < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :transaction_record
end
```

Previously in Rails 4.2, I could do:

`Document.where(transaction_record: @transaction_record)`

and it would return the results just fine, even though the actual field is `transaction_record_id`.

I upgraded to Rails 5.0 and then 5.1, and the above query silently fails.  Doesn't throw any errors, just doesn't work.

I had to tweak it to be:

`Document.where(transaction_record_id: @transaction_record.id)`

and it seems to work just fine now.  I haven't seen anything in the docs about changes to the `where()` criteria; did I just miss it, or is there something else going on here?